# Java Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dato_ error

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un método en Java para leer de fichero unos datos, quiero descartar aquellas líneas que sean comentarios, es decir, que empiecen por *#* , por cuestiones relacionadas con otra clase que le voy a pasar el dato, creé un objeto de esa clase, que le paso el dato en el momento de leerlo del fichero, el problema es que me sale un error que no entiendo, relativo a las referencias constantes, el IDE me sugiere cambiar el atributo `dato_` a `static`, desconozco por qué. Aquí dejo el código:

```
public class InputTape {



    MaquinaRam dato_;

    public static void leeFicheroDatos(String archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String cadena;
        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] datos = cadena.split(" "); 
                for(int i=0;i<datos.length;i++) {
                    if(datos[0]!="#") {
                        dato_ = new MaquinaRam(datos[i]); //LINEA DEL ERROR
                    }
                }
        }
        b.close();
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Porque tu funcion es estatica. Entonces necesita guardar sus datos en variables estaticas. Si lo llamas desde fuera de un objeto, en cual de todos los dato_ lo guardaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu método `public static void leeFicheroDatos(String archivo)` lo tienes declarado como `static`.

Los métodos declarados como `static`tienen varias restricciones:

1. Sólo pueden llamar directamente a otros métodos `static` de su
   clase.
2. Solo pueden acceder directamente a las **variables static** de su **clase**. Es por esto por lo que te da error.
3. No pueden referirse a `this` o `super` de ninguna manera.

**El 2º punto es el que te falla a tí.**